# How to use Lombok @SuperBuilder on Abstract classes with final fields

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder, lombok

Given the following classes with the Lombok annotations `@Data` and `@SuperBuilder`

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent {

    protected final String userId;
    protected final Instant requestingTime;
}

@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {

    private final Instant beginningDate;
    private final Instant endingDate;
    private final Collection<String> fields;
}
```

I am getting the following error appearing over the `@Data` annotation in the `Child` class:

> Implicit super constructor Parent() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor.

Is there a way to configure a non-default constructor on the `Child` class's `@Data` annotation in order to have all `final` fields on both the `Child` and `Parent` classes initialized when invoking the Builder?

I have tried a few different combinations of the `@Data`, `@Getter`, `@Setter` annotations with the `@SuperBuilder` annotation on both the child and parent classes, but haven't found a working solution yet. I am using Lombok 1.18.10.

For reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208842/how-to-implements-lombok-builder-for-abstract-class) question is related

***EDIT***

This is effectively the constructor that Lombok should be constructing and invoking on the `SuperBuilder.build()` operation.

```
public Child(
    final String userId,
    final Instant requestingTime,
    final Instant beginningDate,
    final Instant endingDate,
    final Collection<String> fields) {

    super(userId, requestingTime);
    this.beginningDate = beginningDate;
    this.endingDate = endingDate;
    this.fields= fields;
}
```

As requested, this is how I would expect to invoke the builder on the `Child` object.

```
final Child child = Child.Builder()
                         .userId(<value>)
                         .requestingTime(<value>)
                         .beginningDate(<value>)
                         .endingDate(<value>)
                         .fields(<value>)
                         .build();
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, `@Data` generates a `@NoArgsConstructor`, which is just wrong. Actually, `@Data` is wrong per se, as it's meant for mutable classes; `@Value` would be better, but it can't deal with the super constructor either.

So remove `@Data`, add `@Getter`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@ToString` and whatever you need. Don't forget to add `callSuper=true` in the subclass.

---

> This is effectively the constructor that Lombok should be constructing and invoking on the SuperBuilder.build() operation.

```
public Child(
    final String userId,
    final Instant requestingTime,
    final Instant beginningDate,
    final Instant endingDate,
    final Collection<String> fields) {

    super(userId, requestingTime);
    this.beginningDate = beginningDate;
    this.endingDate = endingDate;
    this.fields= fields;
}
```

No, that's not how `SuperBuilder` works. This is actually Lombok can't do as it can't see the super fields. Instead, the builder uses something like

```
public Child(ChildBuilder b) {    
    super(b);
    this.beginningDate = b.beginningDate;
    this.endingDate = b.endingDate;
    this.fields= b.fields;
}
```

You can believe what Jan Rieke says, he wrote it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removing @Data now causes a compilation error because the ```final``` fields are not being initialized. Adding a ```@RequiredArgsConstructor``` to both the ```Child``` and ```Parent``` classes results in an issue in the ```Child``` class stating the ```Parent()``` super constructor is not defined.

Comment: I can implement the correct constructor explicitly in the ```Child``` class - it needs to take the arguments for ```Child``` as well as ```Parent``` and then invoke the ```Parent```'s @RequiredArgsConstructor. Ideally Lombok would be doing this automatically.

Comment: Why do you want an additional constructor at all if you instantiate via builder?

Comment: The additional constructor is not necessary for how I want to instantiate the object, it seems necessary in order for the code to compile. All of the fields in both the ```Parent``` and ```Child``` class are marked ```final```, so without it, the code doesn't compile - unless I am missing something with how ```SuperBuilder``` is designed to work.

Comment: `@SuperBuilder` uses its own special constructor, which just takes a builder instance as argument. No need to define anything else. I just verified that your code compiles just fine once you remove the `@Data`.

Comment: @burtmacklin16 Could you create a full project (e.g., on github) demonstrating your problem? You may have found a bug, but your usage of `SuperBuilder` after the removal of `@Data` is pretty basic and for sure works for many Lombok users, so there must be something special with your setup. Are you using IDEA?

Comment: I am using Eclipse 2018-12.

Answer (score 0):

@Data annotation implicitly generate code for below mentioned functionalities:

---

- setter
- getter
- toString
- equallAndHashCode
- constructor(for required arguments only)

---

It means constructor declaration of loombok will generate code for Parent class will be as mentioned below:

**Person(String userId, Instant requestingTime)**

Similarly for Child class:

**Child(Instant beginningDate, Instant endingDate, Collection fields)**

---

Now as your program is throwing exception that

> Parent()
>   is undefined in parent class.

Please annotate your class with :

> @NoArgsConstructor

This will generate required default constructor.

Comment: If Lombok attempts to use the NoArgsConstructor on the ```Parent``` class through the ```Child``` class's RequiredArgsConstructor, how would it be possible to set the fields in the ```Parent``` class that are marked ```final```?

Comment: @burtmacklin16  As you are using SuperBuilder here, Please try creating objects with builder. Here SuperBuilder will generate the builder for both parent and child. You will be able to set value of parent class fields with child class builder object. Let me know if you feel that sample code may be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the @NoArgsConstructor isn't an option because the final fields on the abstract ```Parent``` class will not be initialized.

Comment: You are initializing child class via Constructor? If yes, can you please share the use case for SuperBuilder annotation here.

Comment: Ideally it would be done through the ```SuperBuilder``` but without the explicit constructor in place that I mentioned in my edit, the code will not even compile.